# Unable to resolve a httpcomponent dependency in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The following dependency is added to my `pom.xml` file, yet Java is unable to resolve the imported class.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

The `httpcomponents` jar exists in my local Maven repository (in `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents`) But I can see in Eclipse that it doesn't show up in the Maven Dependencies.

The usual error persists.

```
The import org.apache.http.entity.mime cannot be resolved
```

I think I'm making some silly error / overlooking something (for example, do I need to add a third party repository in the `pom.xml` file?)

**Edit**

The complete `pom.xml` file is as follows.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.bl</groupId>
  <artifactId>recording</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>recording</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
            <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
            <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
            <version>5.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.wsit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.functionaljava</groupId>
            <artifactId>functionaljava</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>thirdparty-releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Thirdparty Releases</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>xuggle repo</id>
            <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>google-releases</id>
            <name>Google Releases</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-releases</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you compile from the command line? (just to blame the eclipse plugin).

Comment: Can you just force update maven from project properties?

Comment: @ADi How exactly should I do that?

Comment: @wrahool Maven->Update Project->(check Force Update option)->click Ok.

Comment: Just as @Jorge_B Mentioned. Right Click project -> Maven -> tick force update. If the problem is still there,try removing dependency and update project and add it again and update.

Comment: There is a long shot as well, try adding the jar from .m2 folder itself, but try the above mentioned first.

Comment: @Jorge_B I can't find a checkbox within Right click -> Maven. (I'm using Eclipse Indigo.)

Comment: @ADi I cannot do that! It needs to be committed as a Maven project in our repository - so manually adding Jars is out of the question.

Comment: ok follow these: http://s27.postimg.org/e7mk8lz6r/image.png then http://s28.postimg.org/nzbwsemwd/image.png 

In the second image, click on force update

Comment: I faced the same problem long time back, I backed up .m2 folder and deleted it completely. I let eclipse update it again. I know it's a bad habit but I had to.

Comment: @ADi that option isn't there in the menu. Check this screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/YCHNA66.png

Comment: @wrahool what do you have in update dependencies?

Comment: @ADi there is no menu within it. I clicked on it, hoping that it would .. well.. update dependencies. Couldn't notice any change.

Comment: @wrahool Interesting.. I am using kepler, you might have noticed that. Well, you can still try the worst trick, backup .m2, delete everything and let maven update and download everything on its own, it will let maven update addresses. if it doesn't work, restore old .m2 folder.

Comment: At this point you should exit eclipse, and focus on getting the command line compilation of maven to work. Enable all warnings to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had been adding the wrong dependency. This is the correct one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

instead.

(Copied from http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.httpcomponents%7Chttpclient%7C4.3.2%7Cjar)

Answer (score 1):

If the binary appears in your local repository, you don't need to do nothing else.  Just have m2eclipse update your project configuration (right-click on your project -> Maven -> Update project...) and it should solve your dependency

Comment: It didn't work. I updated Maven project configuration AND Maven dependencies.

Comment: Please, can you confirm that you see the specific .jar in: right-click on project, -> properties -> java build path -> libraries tab -> maven dependencies?  In that case, can you confirm that .jar exists in your local repository?

Comment: @wrahool make sure you tick (Force update of snapshots/releases) applies to eclipse IDE